# Configuration centralization for Play2 Scala; or how to stop hardcoding variables

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework-2.0

At the moment, I'm hardcoding several variables like resource names and ports. I would like to move them out of my code.

What are recommended means of implementing a central configuration outside the actual code? Like a file maybe. So that, while the production and development are using same git repository, the configurations would be seperate. I am using Play 2 Framework on Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) library. It loads and parses files that can be a mix of .properties style, JSON, or extended JSON (called HOCON - "Human-Optimized Config Object Notation"), and is the configuration style used by Play 2 itself (and Akka, Spray, and a quickly growing list of other libraries).

Answer (score 2):

In Play's standard `application.conf` file you can include files like so:

`include "file:///..."`

In this file you could override what properties you need to.

Additionally, (as documented in the excellent play [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ProductionConfiguration)), one can specify conf files during app startup like so:

Using -Dconfig.file
You can also specify another local configuration file not packaged into the application artifacts:

```
$ start -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf
```

Using -Dconfig.url
You can also specify a configuration file to be loaded from any URL:

```
$ start -Dconfig.url=http://conf.mycompany.com/conf/prod.conf
```

Note that you can always reference the original configuration file in a new prod.conf file     using the include directive, such as:

```
include "application.conf"

key.to.override=blah
```

Comment: Apparently, [Play2 already uses Typesafe Config](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration). Cheers for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Configuration is likely a mean of taste, but [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) is one of the common libraries to use in scala/play ecosystem (e.g. it is used in akka).